# Publish SCSS file into NPM package Vue-cli 3

Tags: build, sass, vue-cli-3

I am authoring a Vue.js lib on NPM and one of my users is asking me to add my `scss` file into the build so they can modify it.

How can users modify that `scss` file and compile it back to my lib?
Would that be a hack like modifying a lib's source code or is that common practice?

If I externalize that `scss` into a static file (I suspect in `public/` folder), how do I include it from my component?

Is there a documentation about it, I looked into Vue-cli, Webpack, and Google and didn't find a guide.

---

Currently I only export a minified css file into the build and my `scss` resides in my `index.vue` of my component.

My project architecture is:

```
| public/
| src/
| assets/
| components/
  |- my-lib/ // Only this folder gets bundled into dist/
     |- index.vue
|- app.vue // My app documentation.
```

In the `dist/` folder I get:

```
mylib.css
mylib.umd.js
mylib.umd.min.js
mylib.common.js
mylib.umd.min.js
demo.html
```

I bundle my lib (with vue-cli 3) with:

`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name mylib ./src/components/mylib/index.vue --dest ./dist`

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I am having this exact problem and haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Unfortunately still not. :/ I left it for now. If ever you know before me please post your answer here! @J.Molinero